# Save json files in android

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk

I have my files saved on resources folder and when I try to write other thing it does not work. Could anyone help me?

```
public void SaveGameData()
{
    PlayerSavedData aux = new PlayerSavedData();
    aux.allSavedPlayerData = SavePlayerInformation.playerDataList.ToArray<PlayerData> ();

    string dataAsJson = JsonUtility.ToJson (aux);

    string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "playerInformation.json";
    File.WriteAllText (filePath, dataAsJson);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? The file should be stored in `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/files`. Is it not there? Does your app have the appropriate permissions?

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "playerInformation.json";
```

Try this instead

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,"playerInformation.json");
```

Also note that you need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Answer (score 0):

The Resoures folder simply doens't exist any more afer your build. The assets in the Resources folder get packed into the game's archive for assets.
Better you put file in StreamingAssets folder.